# How To Organize An Array By Key String with Integer

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I be able to organize the below array into another array using the integer value provided in the array object key?

```
[
  {
     "itemQty_0": "443"
   },
   {
     "itemDescription_0": "Et aspernatur aspernatur qui sed ut do enim vel dignissimos libero nisi aut adipisci pariatur Est"
   },
   {
      "itemCapCheckbox_0": "on"
   },
   {
     "itemQty_1": "44"
   },
   {
     "itemDescription_1": "44"
   }
]
```

How can I organize this array into another array that looks like this?

```
items: [{
   itemDescription: stringValue,
   itemQty: integerValue,
   itemCapCheckBox: 'on/off'
},{
   itemDescription: stringValue,
   itemQty: integerValue,
   itemCapCheckBox: 'on/off'
 }]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 const result = [];

 for(const obj of items){
   const keyId = Object.keys(obj)[0], [key, id] = keyId.split("_");
   if(result[id]){
     result[id][key] = obj[keyId];
   }else{
     result[id] = { [key] : obj[keyId] };
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and collect properties with the same index into an object. Then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the [map values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) back to an array.

To find the key, you can use [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys, and take the 1st (and only one). Then split the key by underscore to get the property name, and the index.

```js
const items = [{"itemQty_0":"443"},{"itemDescription_0":"Et aspernatur aspernatur qui sed ut do enim vel dignissimos libero nisi aut adipisci pariatur Est"},{"itemCapCheckbox_0":"on"},{"itemQty_1":"44"},{"itemDescription_1":"44"}];

const result = [...items.reduce((m, o) => {
  const oKey = Object.keys(o)[0]; // get the key
  
  const [prop, index] = oKey.split('_'); // get the prop name and the index

  m.has(index) || m.set(index, {}); // if index doesn't exist in the map, and a new entry
  
  m.get(index)[prop] = o[oKey]; // get the object by the index, and assign the value to the prop
  
  return m;
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by splitting the key for key and index part.

```js
var array = [{ itemQty_0: "443" }, { itemDescription_0: "Et aspernatur aspernatur qui sed ut do enim vel dignissimos libero nisi aut adipisci pariatur Est" }, { itemCapCheckbox_0: "on" }, { itemQty_1: "44" }, { itemDescription_1: "44" }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var key = Object.keys(o)[0],
            keys = key.split('_');

        r[keys[1]] = r[keys[1]] || {};
        r[keys[1]][keys[0]] = o[key];
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey Nina. Could you help me understand `r[keys[1]] = r[keys[1]] || {};` ?

Comment: it checks if the object with the index exist, and if not it creates an object.

Comment: What is confusing me is that it seems like the initial value of the accumulator is []. So I take the accumulator is looking for a value with the index of 0 and cannot find it so it sets the initial value from [] to {}?

Comment: the outer (the accumulator) is an array, the inner (item at index) is an object.

Comment: So this is to say that the accumulator can be = [{}] before something can be added such as [{keyname: value}]? Sorry, this has been really difficult to wrap my head around. I understand the basics of how to use an accumulator just that It gets confusing when it checks if there is already a value for the index and knows not to add to the object inside of the array.

Comment: The concept is easy, the execution is difficult.

Comment: the accumulator starts with an empty array, because if there is no element in the array for iterating, the the result is an empty array. otherwise you would get an empty object in the array, which is wrong. at iteration and before an assignment to a property, you need an object, which is checked and assigned first and then the assignment takes place.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think your answer is the easiest to read.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for this we would need to aggregate the array of objects into a structure that looks more like the answer you want. You want to use maybe `Array.reduce` for that.

```
function ReduceItemToArray(acc, item){
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; //Get the key (eg "itemQty_1")
  var [newKey, index] = key.split("_"); //Get newkey and index from key ("itemQty" and "1" respectively)
  var newAcc = [...acc]; //make a copy of the current accumulator
  if(newAcc[Number(index)] === undefined) //If there is no bucket on that index, make an empty one
    newAcc[Number(index)] = {};
  newAcc[Number(index)][newKey] = item[key]; //Add the item
  return newAcc; //Return the new item
}

var items = input.reduce(ReduceItemToArray, []);
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Why do you send the initial value as [] instead of {}?

Comment: Because the item that I am getting back from the `.reduce()` function is an array. I need to pass it an initial value, so I just pass an empty array. in the end, `items` will always be an array.